# typedef equivalent in C# to use C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll, typedef, dllimport

I'm trying to call a C++ structure, exported to a DLL, from C#-Code

This is the C++ interface to the Method I want to call:

```
typedef void *Handle;
typedef void (*Callback)(Info *info);
typedef void (*Timeout)(Info *info);

typedef struct {
    WORD port;
    WORD flag;
    char name[16];
} Info;

__declspec(dllexport) Handle open(Info *info, Callback c,
                           Timeout timeout);
```

[This article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) teached me how to declare the info-struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit,
    Pack=1,Size=36)]
public struct Info
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
        public ushort port;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
        public ushort flag;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
        public char name;
}
```

Then I would import the Method in C#:

```
[DllImport ("MyDLL")] private static extern void Handle open(Info
*info, Callback c, Timeout timeout);
```

Then I'm stucked, because I don't know how to transfer the typedefs of Handle, Callback and Timeout to C#. Any suggestions?

Comment: You certainly can do this in C# (see xanatos' answer), but if you have a lot of nontrivial P/Invoke calls like this one in your project, it may be time to consider implementing a C++/CLI interop layer between your C# code and your C++ code, as it may be less of a pain in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite complex... Try this... It will probably go boom but then you can tell me how it did go boom and I can help you:

```
public class MyDllhelper
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct Info
    {
        public ushort port;
        public ushort flag;
        public fixed byte name[16];

        public unsafe string Name
        {
            get
            {
                fixed (byte* ptr = name)
                {
                    IntPtr ptr2 = (IntPtr)ptr;
                    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr2, 16).TrimEnd('\0');
                }
            }

            set
            {
                fixed (byte* ptr = name)
                {
                    IntPtr ptr2 = (IntPtr)ptr;

                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value);
                    int length = Math.Min(15, bytes.Length);
                    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr2, length);
                    ptr[length] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public VoidRefInfoDelegate C { get; set; }
    public VoidRefInfoDelegate Timeout { get; set; }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate void VoidRefInfoDelegate(ref Info info);

    [DllImport("MyDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern IntPtr open(ref Info info, VoidRefInfoDelegate c, VoidRefInfoDelegate timeout);

    public IntPtr Open(ref Info info, VoidRefInfoDelegate c, VoidRefInfoDelegate timeout)
    {
        C = c;
        Timeout = timeout;
        return open(ref info, C, Timeout);
    }
}
```

Note that you'll have to do something like:

```
public void CMethod(ref MyDllhelper.Info info)
{
    Console.WriteLine("C method called");
}

public void TimeoutMethod(ref MyDllhelper.Info info)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timeout method called");
}

var info = new MyDllhelper.Info();
info.Name = "012345678901234567890"; // Use Name, not name!
info.flag = 1;
info.port = 2;

var helper = new MyDllhelper();
IntPtr handle = helper.Open(ref info, CMethod, TimeoutMethod); // Use Open, not open!
```

You will need to compile the code with the Properties->Build->Allow unsafe code.

There are two or three interesting points in the code: the C array has been converted to a `fixed` byte array. I've added a getter/setter `Name` to handle the conversion from Ansi/ASCII to Unicode and back.

The C function has two callback methods (`c` and `timeout`). To use them, you need to "save" somewhere C#-side the delegates you'll use, because otherwise the garbage collector will free the delegates, and you'll receive an exception (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/6193914/613130). The `C` and `Timeout` properties are used for this.

Comment: it worked perfectly and didn't go boom. thank you so much. Now I have another problem with marshalling arrays. Maybe you could help me one more time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399339/marshalling-float-array-to-c-sharp
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Those typedefs are for callback functions that will be called from the open(..) method that you are calling. Each of those callback functions is going to take a *Info argument. See [answers for calling C++ functions containing callbacks in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659303/calling-c-functions-containing-callbacks-in-c-sharp) for some examples of how those functions are declared. Of course, you're going to need to do more than just declare them; you're going to have to write the code for doing the work in those functions, too.