# Resolving "callback was made on a garbage collected delegate" using unmanaged code

Tags: c#, timer

I'm writing a C# / WPF application that needs to run some code every 10 ms or so (I understand Windows is not real-time). Since I'm running on Windows 7, the system tick of ~15 ms limits me from using the built-in .NET timer types.

I implemented the Multimedia timer as detailed [here] by user mike-z ([High resolution timer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839105/high-resolution-timer-in-c-sharp)), but seem to be running into the same issue hurcan solter was seeing. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in C# to follow his proposed solution:

> create the callback delegate yourself and use GCHandle.Alloc()

I'm not very experienced with C# or managed code, but from what I can tell, the issue is related to this line:

```
timerId = NativeMethods.TimeSetEvent((uint)Interval, (uint)Resolution, TimerCallback, ref userCtx, 1);
```

Where the TimerCallback() function is being garbage collected -- is that right?

So it sounds like I need to create a reference to this callback in my main / managed function, and then pass that to the timer (maybe as an input argument to the `Start()` function) ?

But I'm not sure where I would need to use `GCHandle.Alloc()`, in this case.

Comment: See the answers in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193711/call-has-been-made-on-garbage-collected-delegate-in-c).  You need to keep a reference to the delegate passed into that method. You shouldn't need `GC.Alloc`

Comment: Thank you. Tim's answer was what I needed. I had looked at that question before, but apparently not closely enough.